# Access asking for password when going to Tools/References

Tags: security, ms-access, reference

I'm trying to go to the references on an Access Database.  I'm not very familiar with this database but here's my history with it:

I tried to open the code files once and it asked for a password
Prior developer assured me there was no password on it and he was able to get into the code files just fine.
I then tried and, to my surprise, it no longer asked me for a password
Today I try to get into Tools/References and the password box is back.

Allegedly this mdb is not supposed to be protected.  Any help if figuring out how to get past this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When it demands a password to get at references, does it also require a password to view a code module during the same session?

Comment: That's the funny thing.  The first time I opened it up it did.  Then the previous developer came in for a day, told me it wasn't password protected, and didn't have any trouble opening it on his machine.  I then tried to open it on my machine to show him the password box that was appearing but to my surprise it no longer appeared.  I can still get into code modules without a password now, but not into the tools/references.  However, when I opened up a backed up version of this database I got the password box on both the module and the references once again.

Comment: We got him on a conference call a few minutes ago and he didn't know why the password box was still appearing for the tools/references, but he did know the password and reset it to one we commonly use so I can get it now.  I would just remove the password altogether though if I knew how.

Comment: From the VB editor's main menu, try `Tools->(Your project name) Properties`. Then select the Protection tab on the Project Properties dialog.  Uncheck the box next to "Lock project for viewing".  That may be enough by itself, but I think you can also clear the current password lower on that tab, if needed/wanted.  Honestly, I've almost never fiddled with that option, so I'm uncertain whether this is the fix.  Users get a compiled (MDE) version of the application, so it has no source code to view, and it's not an issue.  I don't need/want to lock out other developers from the original MDB.

Comment: If nothing else is satisfactory, you could create a new database file an import everything you want from the old one.  That could help if the original has some bizarre corruption going on.  Or you could also try decompile.  Search SO for that topic.

Comment: @HansUp Technically it's still unanswered.  But because I like you, I marked one so it will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original programmer removed the password that was required to get into the code, but then we found there was another level of security protecting the project references.  The original programmer couldn't figure out how to remove that password, but he was instead able to change it to something that wasn't personal.

So I never really got the answer I was looking for but I think the moral of the story is that people need to not use personal passwords for their work stuff so that when I take over their work they can just tell me what it is instead of making me wait a month for them to come back and change it.